# How to find if a sentence contains particular word

Tags: python-3.x, fuzzy-logic, fuzzywuzzy

[image]How to find if a sentence contains a particular word in python?

I have two files,

Player [File 1]
Joe doesn't like to play football
Kumar favourite game is hockey
Mohit likes soccer game
Naveen doesn't like cricket
Sachin was a crick player
Savan likes cricket
Vinod likes Basket 
Andy likes volleyball

Game [File 2]

```
hockey
```

soccer
footba
crick
cricket
Basketball

Output expectation:
Player                                  Game          Score [%]
Sachin was a crick player               crick          100
Joe doesn't like to play football       footba         75
Naveen doesn't like cricket             cricket        100
Savan likes cricket                     cricket         100
Vinod likes Basketb                     Basketball     160
Kumar favourite game is hockey          hockey         100
Andy likes volleyball                   null           no match
Mohit likes soccer game                 soccer         100

Score is defined as "len(game)/len(matching word)

If a same player matched with 2 games then highest score should come.

like this I have more than 10000 records.

Comment: How do you differentiate sentences? Can you fix your file formatting? Also look into `word in sentence`.

Comment: How is the score to be calculated?

Comment: Score based on matching variables. If cricket = cricket then 100%.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to read in the Player File and break it into sentences

```
>>> with open ('testfiles/player.txt') as f:
...    sentences = []
...    for line in f:
...        sentences.append (line.strip ())
>>> sentences
['Sachin was a cricket player', 'Mohit likes soccer game', 'Kumar favourite game is hockey', "Joe doesn't like to play football"]
```

Do the same for Game in a different way but convert it into a set for uniqueness and efficiency:

```
>>> with open ('testfiles/games.txt') as f:
...    games = set ([line.strip () for line in f])
...
>>> games
{'hockey', 'crick', 'soccer', 'volleyball', 'badminton'}
```

Now we just look for the keyword in the sentence and arrive at the output below.

```
>>> game_score = {}
...game_found = set ()
...for sentence in sentences:
...    for game in games:
...        if game in sentence:
...            game_score.setdefault (game, [sentence, '100%'])  # Save game name as key and set sentence a list of value that include sentence and % matching
...            game_found.add (sentence)  # Save the game name that are found to be checked against the game name that isn't found
>>> game_score
{'hockey': ['Kumar favourite game is hockey', '100%'], 'crick': ['Sachin was a cricket player', '100%'], 'soccer': ['Mohit likes soccer game', '100%']}
>>> game_found
{'Mohit likes soccer game', 'Kumar favourite game is hockey', 'Sachin was a cricket player'}
```

Compare the game_found against the player's sentences and add the games not found into the game_score:

```
>>> for i, sentence in enumerate (sentences):
...    if sentence not in game_found:
...        game_name = 'null-%d' % i  # Dictionary key cannot contain duplicate
...        game_score.setdefault (game_name, [sentence, 'No match'])
...
>>> game_score
{'hockey': ['Kumar favourite game is hockey', '100%'], 'crick': ['Sachin was a cricket player', '100%'], 'soccer': ['Mohit likes soccer game', '100%'], 'null-3': ["Joe doesn't like to play football", 'No match']}
```

Finally, print the results:

```
>>> print ('Output%sGame%sMatching Score' % (' ' * 35, ' ' * 10))
...for k in game_score:
...    spacing = 41 - len (game_score [k][0])
...    print ('%s%s%s%s%s' % (game_score [k][0], ' ' * spacing, k, ' ' * (55 - (len (game_score [k][0]) + spacing + len (k))), game_score [k][1]))
...
Output                                   Game          Matching Score
Kumar favourite game is hockey           hockey        100%
Sachin was a cricket player              crick         100%
Mohit likes soccer game                  soccer        100%
Joe doesn't like to play football        null-3        No match
```

You should come up with a logic to deal with sentences that has multiple sports such as "Jane plays both hockey and soccer.

Comment: Just a heads up, after looking at the markdown for the question, it was clear that each sentence and game was on a separate line. So try `with open(file1) as f: sentences = f.read().splitlines()`. You're also missing the output formatting and score (not that the scoring rubric is specified).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

But in the function how to calculate score and one more thing if there is no match in the sentence, that sentence should show as "no match".

thanks in advance

Comment: @dreamzboy  
I have edited the question with more details. Thanks in advance

Comment: @NAVEENN.C, you should not edit the question after two years, but probably ask a new question with a minimified example of what your problem is and not the full context

Comment: Not only that, it's not nice to unmark an answer after changing your original question twice and twice I had to update the answer.